# Windows Application Framework Properties in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, ide

To familiarize you with what's going on, I am working on a personal project of mine in Visual Studio 2010 PRO. It is a desktop/form application and there is a splash screen within my project. The splash screen is supposed to load and stay in focus for a few seconds and then it should be closed; leaving the main form rendered.

When I run the application the spash screen displays then it closes and ends the whole application. I believe I need to change the default settings in "Windows application framework properties", but it is grayed out and I cannot make any selections. (Right click project file in solution explorer --> Application --> Windows application framework)

Please extend some help if you know how I can configure these settings. In the meanwhile, I have forced to use frmSplashScreen.Hide() to make it work and click Stop Debugging when I want the program to stop, which is not very practical.

Thanks in advance. I reproduced some of the code below.

```
Private Sub tmrSplashScreen_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles tmrSplashScreen.Tick
        'Close the form after time value specified
        Me.Hide()
        frmHomeScreen.Show()
        frmHomeScreen.Focus()
    End Sub
```

Comment: you should make sure that you open the file from your parent. In this case that would be the main form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

main form

```
dim splshScreen as frmSplashscreen = New frmSplashscreen()

 private sub openSplashscreen()

     'you are showing who is the parent by sending "me" with the showdialog
     splshScreen.showdialog(me)
 end sub
```

splash form

```
Private Sub frmSplashscreen(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

'Do something cool to load anything

  if load = true then
     me.close()
  end if 

end sub
```

so basicly send in parent with opened dialog. Afterwards give a condition to your load and make sure it closes when it done. If you just use me.close it should be fine and close itself

Comment: Thank you very much for assisting me. The program is running the way I want it to at this point (still not even at the tip of the ice berg in terms of the application as a whole). My close statement for the splash screen is placed within a tick event.

Although, I would still like to know why the options in the Project Properties are grayed out and prevents me from changing the behavior there.